# No icon when sharing with Sharekit

Tags: objective-c, facebook, sharekit

I am trying to do a really basic sharing on Facebook from my app, with ShareKit. Most things looks ok, but I don't understand why there's no icon to the left, just the small one in the footer. I can't find a way to put it there. How do I customize it? For me it looks like the left picture I attach, but I would like to have it like the right.

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/...?mt=8"];
item = [SHKItem URL:url title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I'm playing someGame on my iPhone! My Highscore is %i, think you can beat it?", 456]];

[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

[image: For me it's like the left, but I would like to have like the right one.]

Comment: The spray can annotations alone should get +1 for awesomeness.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot out of the box. This dialog is provided by the Facebook SDK, which is just built into ShareKit's files - unchanged.

I am sure if you do a bit of digging around in ShareKit's folders you'll find the Facebook SDK, but I am not sure if you're allowed to edit its appearance (I know you aren't allowed to change the Share button for example)

With regards to the icon - this is loaded from the web and **cannot be changed**. The dialog comes from the Facebook website directly and somehow intercepting it and putting it on your own website would create an invalid request.

**Edit:** Based on your lovely edit (love the spray annotations :P), you can achieve this in the settings page for your app in Facebook. To do this, head over to Facebook's developer app (should be in the applications section of your Facebook account) and upload a large resolution icon for your app. Remember, it asks for a small 16x16 icon and the same one in different sizes, if it finds no icon with the sufficient size it'll display nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the picture to make it more clear how I want it. Maybe I should dig in the Facebook Connect tutorials instead.

Comment: I really put my soul in that editing :) But I have that max 75x75 logotype picture uploaded too. Is that what you mean with large resolution icon?